# How to create a table to count with a conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case

I have a database with a lot of columns with pass, fail, blank indicators
I want to create a function to count each type of value and create a table from the counts. The structure I am thinking is something like
| Value | x                | y                 |  z |
|-------|------------------|-------------------|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| pass  | count if x=pass  | count if y=pass   |  count if z=pass |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| fail  | count if x=fail  | count if y=fail   |count if z=fail   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| blank | count if x=blank | count if y=blank  | count if z=blank  |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| total | count(x)         | count(y)          | count (z)  |   |   |   |   |   |   |

where x,y,z are columns from another table.

I don't know which could be the best approach for this
thank you all in advance

I tried this structure but it shows syntax error

```
CREATE FUNCTION Countif (columnx nvarchar(20),value_compare nvarchar(10))
RETURNS Count_column_x AS
BEGIN
    IF columnx=value_compare
    count(columnx)
END
RETURN
END
```

Also, I don't know how to add each count to the actual table I am trying to create

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Your question as stands really isn't clear either. Sample data and expected results, both in *consumable formats* will help us help you.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to create a new table? Or a resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional counting (or any conditional aggregation) can often be done inline by placing a `CASE` expression inside the aggregate function that conditionally returns the value to be aggregated or a NULL to skip.

An example would be `COUNT(CASE WHEN SelectMe = 1 THEN 1 END)`. Here the aggregated value is `1` (which could be any non-null value for `COUNT()`. (For other aggregate functions, a more meaningful value would be provided.) The implicit `ELSE` returns a `NULL` which is not counted.

For you problem, I believe the first thing to do is to `UNPIVOT` your data, placing the column name and values side-by-side. You can then group by value and use conditional aggregation as described above to calculate your results. After a few more details to add (1) a totals row using `WITH ROLLUP`, (2) a `CASE` statement to adjust the labels for the blank and total rows, and (3) some `ORDER BY` tricks to get the results right and we are done.

The results may be something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(U.Value) = 1 THEN 'Total'
        WHEN U.Value = '' THEN 'Blank'
        ELSE U.Value
        END AS Value,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN U.Col = 'x' THEN 1 END) AS x,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN U.Col = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS y
FROM @Data D
UNPIVOT (
  Value
  FOR Col IN (x, y)  
) AS U
GROUP BY U.Value WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY
    GROUPING(U.Value),
    CASE U.Value WHEN 'Pass' THEN 1 WHEN 'Fail' THEN 2 WHEN '' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END,
    U.VALUE
```

Sample data:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| Pass | Pass |
| Pass | Fail |
| Pass |  |
| Fail |  |

Sample results:

| Value | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pass | 3 | 1 |
| Fail | 1 | 1 |
| Blank | 0 | 2 |
| Total | 4 | 4 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KqlUwv6g) for a working example.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! thank you very much! Will try this approach now

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a generic solution like a function with value as parameter.

Perhaps, you could create a view grouping your data and after call this view filtering by your value.

Your view body would be something like that

```
select value, count(*) as Total
from table_name
group by value
```

Feel free to explain your situation better so I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [grouping by](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_group_by.asp) the status column.

```
select status, count(*) as total
from some_table
group by status
```

Rather than making a whole new table, consider using a [view](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp). This is a query that looks like a table.

```
create view status_counts as
  select status, count(*) as total
  from some_table
  group by status
```

You can then `select total from status_counts where status = 'pass'` or the like and it will run the query.

---

You can also create a ["materialized view"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view). This is like a view, but the results are written to a real table. [SQL Server is special in that it will keep this table up to date for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view#SQL_Server).

```
create materialized view status_counts with distribution(hash(status))
  select status, count(*) as total
  from some_table
  group by status
```

You'd do this for performance reasons on a large table which does not update very often.